# How to execute function stored as a string without eval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me preface this question by saying there may be a completely different solution than my title so let me tell you what I am after entirely.

Basically I have a series of menu links. The `href` in all the links are storing jQuery functions, not URL's (to control [turn.js](http://turnjs.com) book script). So one of the `href`'s may look like so:

```
<li id="menu-item-68" class="home menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-68">
  <a href="$('#primary').turn(‘page’,1);"></a>
</li>
```

The request is simple...on `click()` of a menu item i need to execute the contents of the `href`. My first thought was to run through each link and store a temp string of the `href` and then use `eval()` but that looks to be a bad option from what I read.

So, how can I execute the contents of my `href` quickly and safely?

Comment: Could you post the code you have.

Comment: Well it depends. Is the content of href coming from you or is it user provided? Because if you have control over the content, eval might not be a bad choice.

Comment: `Let me preface this question by saying there may be a completely different solution than my title so let me tell you what I am after entirely.` Then it's a poor title. It also does not need tags in it.

Comment: I added a link that Wordpress generates. Note that Wordpress adds 'http://' before everything so using jQuery I have purposely eliminated that from every href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use the onclick event?

```
<a onclick="function(){$('#primary').turn('page', 2); return false;}" href="#">Click me!</a>
```

Alternately, since you're using JQuery, you could `.bind()` the event:

```
<script>
    $('a.clickable').bind('click', function(e){
         var pageNum = $(this).attr('data-page');
         $(#primary).turn('page', pageNum);
         return false;
    });
</script>
<body>
   <a class='clickable' data-page='2' href='#'>Click me!</a>
```

Alternately, since you only have access to the `href` attribute, you COULD do this, which is the easy way out:

```
 <a href="javascript:$('#primary').turn('page', 2)">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: This looks great, except I can't add attributes to my link since it's Wordpress doing the work. I mean - I COULD but I don't want to hack about the core.

Comment: And of course trying that (which yes I thought of :) ) Wordpress does not like and completely removes it before saving the link! So, I will probably be using this method anyway since I found another big unrelated flaw in the menu. I need to create a somewhat static menu now and this should do it, I'll let you know shortly.

Comment: This works great! I edited your `.bind()` example though, since the href is a hash and you added a custom attribute the code technically doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few solutions here.  You might want to look into using something like [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone) which provides something called routers that would aid you in navigation.

Or to hack up something similar, set each of your `href` tags to point to a new `#` anchor:

`<a href="#2">next page</a>`

and then attach a listener to the `hashchange` event.  When the event fires, the user has clicked on the link.  Then access the hash `window.location.hash` and use that as the argument to a function which does what you need it to do.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(event){
    $('#primary').turn('page', window.location.hash.slice(1));
}
```

The `slice` is there since `window.location.hash` includes the `#` character.

---

EDIT

I notice you updated saying you use wordpress and you're editing out the `http://` part of your URLs.  If you're using the `hashchange` event you don't need to since `href="#2"` is the same as `href="http://mysite.post.com/this_post/#2"`

Comment: I should mention that `hashchange` has some browser support caveats, so you might have to do something to handle that.  If you Google it, you'll see what I mean.  Also, if you're unconcerned with later browsers, you can always look into the history navigation API...

Comment: This doesn't appear to be doing anything in Firefox.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't keep trying this method because I had to hack apart the menu anyway and do something different. The below solution worked in my new scenario. Thank you for the help though, never knew about the `hashchange()` function, looks pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply simulate a click event on the links in that case? In other words, if you already have jquery loaded `$("a#identifier").click()`. In your current scenario that seems to be the easiest way.

Comment: If you trigger the link by jQuery, the code inside href attribute will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I've a similar issue and solved it like this:

In your script, define a function like:

`$.fn.DoSomething=function (MyOption){
    window.alert(MyOption);
};`

And in your link href call the function like `javascript:$.fn.DoSomething('Hello');`